# Is it possible to update multiple columns using different criteria in one statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I need to set all columns to 0 if they are negative.  Currently I do it one column at a time:

```
UPDATE #ListingRank SET Distance = 0 WHERE Distance < 0
UPDATE #ListingRank SET ActionDays = 0 WHERE ActionDays < 0
UPDATE #ListingRank SET Price = 0 WHERE Price < 0
UPDATE #ListingRank SET Beds = 0 WHERE Beds < 0
UPDATE #ListingRank SET Baths = 0 WHERE Baths < 0
UPDATE #ListingRank SET SqFt = 0 WHERE SqFt < 0
```

Is it possible to do the same in a single statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN`

```
UPDATE #ListingRank
SET Distance = (CASE WHEN Distance < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Distance END),
    ActionDays = (CASE WHEN ActionDays < 0 THEN 0 ELSE ActionDays END),
    Price = (CASE WHEN Price < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Price END),
    Beds = (CASE WHEN Beds < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Beds END),
    Baths = (CASE WHEN Baths < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Baths END),
    SqFt = (CASE WHEN SqFt < 0 THEN 0 ELSE SqFt END)
```

Comment: Suggest adding a `WHERE Distance < 0 OR ActionDays < 0 ...` to reduce load.